# thread is not a member of std c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, std

I'm having this problem where i can't use threads because i keep getting the error "'thread' is not a member of 'std'".

I am using MinGW with c++11 as a compiler flag.. On the little program i made yesterday it worked fine. Basically i want to play a "beep"-song while playing a little guessing game with pseudo random numbers.

```
int rnumber, guess, maxrand;

std::thread t1(pinkpanther);
t1.detach();

cout << "What do you want the maximum Number to be? ";
cin >> maxrand;

rnumber = randy(maxrand);

//Start
cout << endl << "This is a game!" << endl << "You have 5 tries to guess the random number generated by this program, have fun" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
{
    cout << "Your guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess < rnumber)
    {
        cout << "Your guessed number is smaller than the answer! Try again!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else if (guess > rnumber)
    {
        cout << "Your guessed number is bigger than the answer! Try again!" << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "you guessed the right number!";
        break;
    }
}





return 0;
```

it always gives me the same error 
`||In function 'int main()':|
'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
't1' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`

and i really dont know why anymore

Edit: pinkpanther() just plays the pinkpanther song i found in "beeps"

Edit2: i have a couple libs included (windows,thread,ctime and ctdlib)

Comment: Did you `#include <thread>`?

Comment: seems like the first couple of lines got lost during copy&paste. There are some lines that are less relevant, but most likely the first ones (or the fact that there is something missing) are important

Comment: yes i have, i will edit so you can see i

Comment: Also please read about [mcve]. It is easier for us to help you if your code does not contain stuff that isnt relevant to the question. For example I bet your code would produce the same error if you removed the whole loop

Comment: MinGW is known for not supporting `std::thread`. MinGW-w64 is an alternative which does.

Comment: i used the latest mingw, and i already have a program using threads and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you present never does  `#include <thread>`. So how is the compiler supposed to know what a `std::thread` is?

Fix your problem by adding `#include <thread>` to the top of your file.

Also make sure you use a compiler that actually supports C++11 (or later) and `std::thread`.

Comment: Im sorry im new here, should have written down my included libs of course, but it is included

Comment: @SergeyA MinGW-w64 does, and has since GCC 4.7.

Comment: So i will try again with MinGW-w64 and report if it helped

Answer (score 2):

What MinGW build did you use? If you got one with the Win32 threading model, it doesn't support C++11 threads; you should instead grab one with the POSIX threading model (winpthreads-based), but mind you, it's quite buggy.

Comment: What do you mean by buggy?

Comment: i downloaded the latest mingw of the (6.3.0-1 i think?), i also have a program running where it just compiles without problems

Comment: @rubenvb I mean that we lost a week tracing a race condition in thread startup down into winpthreads code, we managed to reduce the bug to a simple reproducible case and the bug is still open. After seeing the internals of winpthreads, I don't want to touch that stuff with a ten foot pole. Currently we are using a MinGW build with the Win32 threading model (made by you, by the way!) and libstdc++ headers patched with a vanilla C++/Win32 reimplementation of `std::thread` & co.

Comment: @Grimmboy the gcc+MinGW distribution exists in several different "flavors", in particular regarding threading model (Win32, POSIX and a new experimental one) and exception handling model (sjlj, dw2 and SEH), and binary releases are provided by different people/projects. Saying you have "the latest version" doesn't mean much.

Comment: Latest commonly available MinGW  is 8.1.0 - get it from https://nuwen.net/ - it supports std::thread.

Comment: Would downvoters mind to explain what's incorrect in my answer? Unless something happened in the last three months, the "Win32 threading model" build misses all the gthreads part related to creating/managing threads and to condition variables, and libstdc++ expects full gthreads to provide `std::thread`. When instead MinGW is compiled with the so-called POSIX threading model, the winpthreads library is used to provide a full gthreads implementation (so libstdc++ provides C++11 threading goodness), but in my experience winpthreads is still dangerously buggy and mostly unmantained.